# java generic type parameter with newInstance

Tags: java, generics

I am not sure why Java is requiring me to cast the return of the makeInstance method to T? What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to accomplish this?

```
public class Scratch {

    public <T extends Base> T freshen(T instance) {
        //why do I need to cast this to T
        return makeInstance(instance.getClass());
    }

    public <T extends Base> T makeInstance(Class<T> type) {
        try {
            return type.newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Scratch.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Scratch.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static final class Base {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason Java wants you to cast the result is that `T` returned from `makeInstance` method is not guaranteed to be the same as `T` of `freshen` method.  The reason for it is that `getClass()` does not return `Class<T>`. Instead, it returns `Class<? extends X>`, where `X` is the erasure of the static type of `instance`, i.e. `Object`. That's where the compiler's chain of inference stops: it cannot infer from that call that the return type would be `T`, requiring you to do the cast.

An alternative to casting the instance would be casting the class, like this:

```
return makeInstance((Class<T>)instance.getClass());
```

Comment: "`getClass()` returns `Class<?>`" `getClass()` actually returns `Class<? extends |X|>`, where `|X|` is the erasure of the static type of `instance`, which in this case is `Object`.

Answer (score 1):

The root cause for your problem is "type erasure": when the Java compiler compiles the body of the `freshen()` method it essentially replaces the `T` type with its upper bound, namely: `Base`.

So here's the reasoning the compiler is doing:
- `instance` is of type `Base` (as I said, `T` was replaced with `Base`)
- `.getClass()` is invoked on a variable of type `Base` so the return value of this call is `Class<? extends Base`>
- the parameter that is passed to `makeInstance()` is therefore, from the compiler's point of view, of type `Class<? extends Base>`. Consequently the `T` inside `makeInstance()` is also `Base` => the method returns `Base`

Comment: Very good explanation. I only picked other because he gave me a good solution. Thanks

Comment: @cyberoblivion you can up-vote it to indicate that it is valuable to future readers of your question

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem using following.

```
public class Scratch<T extends Base> {

    public T freshen(T instance) {
        // No need to cast this to T
        return makeInstance(instance.getClass());
    }

    public T makeInstance(Class<T> type) {
        try {
            return type.newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Scratch.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Scratch.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static final class Base {

    }

}
```

Hope this helps.